# Stored procedure always return 0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

The memberStatus always return 0. But when I run the query individually it works properly.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getMySubjectLists;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE getMySubjectLists(
     IN myID    INT,        
     IN GID     INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE memberStatus INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COALESCE(status,0) into memberStatus from member_access where group_id = GID and subject_id = 0 and topic_id = 0 and subtopic_id = 0 
        and member_id = myID;

        insert into apps_log values(0,memberStatus,GID,myID,"",now());  

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Create Table for member_access is as follow. The procedure is not working only for this particular table. I tried with other tables, it worked.

```
CREATE TABLE `member_access` (
 `seqno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `mapid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subtopic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `access_code` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `delegate_code` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `specialid1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `specialid2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `specialid3` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`seqno`),
 KEY `indx1` (`mapid`,`access_code`,`status`),
 KEY `mig1` (`mapid`,`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: are you using any reporting tool or program to display result of this procedure?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you indicated. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b70a9/1).

Comment: I tried with other table its working but for this particular table member_access i am not able to retrive values. I added the create table.

Comment: With the new table structure also it seems to work. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/660c2/1).